# Запятые перед первой и второй И

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и, повторяющийся-союз

`Всë выше(,) и выше(,) и выше!`

Нужны зыпятые? Если да, на каком основании?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятые нужны: ***Всë выше, и выше, и выше!***

[Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101) (Розенталь):

> **6.** Если однородных членов предложения более двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая ставится между всеми однородными членами: *Листья в поле **пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят; Лён, и полотна, и пряжу** несут; А вокруг были **дым, и бой, и смерть***.

Answer (score 1):

***Всë выше, и выше, и выше!***

**Повторение союз *И*** со второго однородного члена. Союз И имеет **усилительное** значение.

**Примечание:** в некоторых предложениях для большей выразительности слова могут повторяться, например:
*Зимы *ждала, ждала* природа*. (А.С. Пушкин)

**Повторяющиеся слова однородными членами не являются.**

Тем не менее мы **обозначаем перечисление** по правилам для однородных членов.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

(1) **[§ 16. Запятая при повторяющихся словах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105#pp105)**

1. Запятая ставится между повторяющимися словами, произносимыми с интонацией перечисления и обозначающими:

5. усиление **обстоятельственного значения:** Страшно, страшно поневоле средь неведомых равнин! (П.); И ближе, ближе всё зву

(2) **[Розенталь, пункт 6](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)**

6. Если однородных членов предложения более двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая ставится между всеми однородными членами: *Листья в поле **пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят.***

(3) **Словарь**

**И, союз. 1.** Соединяет однородные члены предложения и предложения, представляющие собой однородные сообщения.  // Соединяет слова, **которые повторяются для усиления значения** или для выражения длительности действия, **интенсивности, проявления признака,** качества, чрезмерного изобилия, количества чего-л. *Стоит и стоит перед глазами. Дни короче и короче! Метель становилась всё сильнее и сильнее. До самого горизонта тянулась степь и степь.*